# Dividing the hexadecimal colour space into bins

Tags: c++, opencv

To divide the gray-scale colour space into bins I just divide 255 by `nbins`. To determine a gray-scale colour bin I simply check between which bin range the colour sits in. So dividing gray-scale colour space into bins I get and is trivial. And I know, for example, that the colours from 0 to 25 share some similarity - they are quite dark/black.

But what about dividing hexadecimal colour space into bins? Do I simply do the same thing; divide 16 (billon?) into `nbins`? And do those bins share some sort of similarity - like how 0 to 25 in gray scale is similar in shade, is 0x000 to 0x100 similar in shade?

My usecase is to colour reduce an image then count pixel colours (in hexadecimal) but I will sort these into bins as opposed to counting individual colours.

Does OpenCV have some functions to already divide the hexadecimal colour space? Would I be better avoiding hexadecimal and moving to Hue channel only? Would I be effectively working with the same stuff as hexadecimal except not have the huge range hexadecimal has?

Comment: do kmeans cluster on the color

Comment: There is no hexadecimal color space. Hexadecimal and decimal numbers are the exact same numbers with the same rules, just written differently.

Answer (score 0):

They're (as the comment states) not so much "hexadecimal" colors as "RGB" colors.

Now, what you can do is to divide R, G and B *each* into `nbins`, but that would give you `nbins*nbins*nbins` total. Instead, you might want to consider dividing them into `std::cbrtn(bins)` (cube root) each. You might have some rounding effects there.

You can also sub-divide the HSV representation. This is the same color space, but expressed differently. In this case, it's not nearly as obvious how you'd partition HSV space. For whiteish colors (V~1) and very dark/black (V~0), Hue is not well defined. You can of course use the method given above, just use a simple partition of each individual component. But this won't give you results that are equally nice. You're using too many of your `nbins` to differentiate hues near white and black.

The real-world approach to color reduction would be [Floyd-Steinberg dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering). Probably overkill for you.